# Silverlight 3: Techniques for adjusting to screen resolution

Tags: silverlight, xaml, screen-resolution

My developer's box has a screen resolution of 1680 x 1050.  I'm developing a full-screen Silverlight 3 application that I'm considering deploying to the Internet.  So, I want to make sure the application looks good on a variety of screen resolutions.  I just started testing on other boxes, the first one having a screen resolution of 1024 x 768.  During the test I found some of the pages on the application were partially truncated.  It seems the controls on the page didn't adjust for the lower screen resolution.  So, I'm looking for some tips on how to make a Silverlight application, to the extent possible, adjust for screen resolution.  For example, are there things one should or should not do on XAML to make adapting to screen resolution easier?  Should I just optimize for a minimum screen resolution?  Your thoughts and suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

- You can easily enforce a minimum acceptable resolution by setting the `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` properties of your root visual. (Of course, this should be less than the minimum screen resolution to account for browser chrome.)
- Try to specify absolute `Width` and `Height` only when necessary: for example, for images or icons of fixed dimensions, or for obvious cases like `TextBox`es (whose width should reflect the average length of the data entered).
- `Grid` panels are excellent for mixing scalable and fixed layout areas. The star sizing specification takes a bit of getting used to--it's not as simple as a percentage-based proportioning--but it's much more flexible, especially in combination with row/column min/max dimensions.
- You don't really need to test on multiple resolutions unless you're interested in testing a range of dots per inch--just resize the browser to approximate different screens. Since there's always a bit of give and take depending on the user's browser configuration, you'll have to account for some variance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your application scale with the Silverlight Toolkit ViewBox or make it strech with layout controls like the Grid, StackPanel, and WrapPanel.  Make your main UserControl have a Width and Height of Auto (or remove the width and height entirely) and the size of the app will resize to the size of the parent div (the default HTML template uses 100%x100%).  Then just resize the browser accordingly.  IE8 has developer tools that can help you see your app resized to specific screen resolutions.

Testing on a variety of screen resolutions is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I covered the resizing of elements and making it resolution independent on another thread.

You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226841/resolution-issue-in-silverlight/2237110#2237110), there are multiple ways to sizing and resizing things automatically.